# Matlab: Why is correlation NaN when using 'corrcoef'?

Tags: matlab

When I run `corrcoef` to find correlation coefficients among two data arrays, I get NaNs. It only does that for one batch of data. Here is a [download link to the data within .mat file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h46edm4bmrdzhw9/datafile.mat?dl=0).

I run this code

```
[R(1).R,R(1).P,R(1).RL,R(1).RU] = corrcoef([data.Series1], [data.Series2], 'rows', 'pairwise');
```

and it gives me

```
NaN   NaN
NaN     1
```

for R, P, RL, and RU.

I don't think the NaNs in the data are the problem because I use `'pairwise'` parameter for `corrcoef` function, which tells it to ignore NaNs.

I copied the same data into Microsoft Excel and it calculated the correlation coefficient just fine. Here is the [Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzxt0axr79s1rcl/datafile.xlsx?dl=0&preview=datafile.xlsx) with the coefficient of correlation calculated. Why doesn't `corrcoef` do it? What can possibly go wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to download this file and plug it in to see what happened.

Yes you are right that when treating the data with `pairwise` functionality, the pairs with anyone element = NaN are effectively removed from the operation;

BUT - what about INFs? In your [data.Series1] - you have INF entries, and that seems to be causing the problem.

I extracted your data series into 2 vectors A and B:

```
A = [data.Series1];
B = [data.Series2];

 >> max (A)
   ans =
   Inf
```

Now by setting Inf to NaN:

```
 A(isinf(A)) = NaN;
 [R(1).R,R(1).P,R(1).RL,R(1).RU] = corrcoef(A,B, 'rows', 'pairwise');

>> R.RL

    ans =

        1.0000   -0.0794
       -0.0794    1.0000
```

Discussions: Obviously INF will not work in MATLAB, but the question is why did it work for Excel? Did Excel turn Inf into NaN by default when using `CORREL`? Because the data certainly got loaded in as inf.

---------- EDIT ---------

After carefully reading the excel instructions:

Remarks from [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CORREL-function-995dcef7-0c0a-4bed-a3fb-239d7b68ca92)

"If an array or reference argument contains text, logical values, or empty cells, those values are ignored; however, cells with the value zero are included."

So when a NaN and Inf gets loaded into excel, they are treated as Strings(Text format) not numbers, and thus are ignored - this should explain why it worked on Excel.

Comment: Whoa that's something I wasn't aware of. Apparently there are also Infs :) I think something must have been divided by zero along the way. I thought divisions by zero were NaNs. Thank you! I spent a day trying to figure out what is wrong with that data.

Comment: No worries, always check your input if the output is not expected, sometimes it could be really small things that cause you to waste time looking at the entire process.